# Assuming that workers' salaries in your company are uniformly distributed between $\$35,000$ and $\$45,000$ per year

Tags: probability, statistics

> Assuming that workers' salaries in your company are uniformly distributed between $\$35,000$ and $\$45,000$ per year, calculate the average salary in your company.

Please help. How to start? Thanks.

Comment: If $X \sim uniform(a,b)$, then $E[X] = \frac{a+b}{2}$

Comment: many thanks  and also $$var(x)=(a-b)^2/12$$ is that correct ?

Comment: Yes it is. See Simon's answer below for more detail to understand where the formula for the expectation of a uniform random variable comes from

Answer (score 3):

Intuitively, the salary is anywhere in the range $[35000,45000]$ with equal probability, so the mean should be $40000$.

Formally: we could write the probability density function, $p$, as a function of salary $s$ in dollars as

$$p(s) = \begin{cases} {1 \over 45,000-35,000} &, \ 35,000 \leq s \leq 45,000 \\ 0 & , \ \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$

The average then is

$$E[s] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty sp(s) \ ds \\ = \int_{35,000}^{45,000} {s \over 45,000-35,000} \ ds \\ = {1 \over 45,000-35,000} \frac{45,000^2 - 35,000^2}{2} \\ = \frac{35,000+45,000}{2} \\ = 40,000$$

You can see from this answer how to derive the general formula Breton gives above for the mean of a uniform distribution.